# Unable to start RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, erl

I have Googled so much, and not got any proper answer.So , I am posting this question for better result.

I have already killed the `RabbitMQ` server process .

Now when I am trying to start it again, it shows

> > ### Command
> >
> > ```
> > rabbitmqctl start_app
> > ```

---

> > ### Error
> >
> > ```
> > {error_logger,{{2013,11,4},{11,26,8}},"Cookie file /ngs/app/ttet/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only",[]}
> > {error_logger,{{2013,11,4},{11,26,8}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{auth,init,['Argument__1']}},    {pid,<0.18.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{"Cookie file /ngs/app/curot/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},    {line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,297}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},    {line,227}]}]},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,321}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.9.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.16.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,24},{reductions,401}],[]]}
> > {error_logger,{{2013,11,4},{11,26,8}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},        {errorContext,start_error},{reason,{"Cookie file /ngs/app/ttet/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,285}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,139}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,297}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,auth},{mfargs,{auth,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
> > {error_logger,{{2013,11,4},{11,26,8}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
> > {error_logger,{{2013,11,4},{11,26,8}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
> > {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
> > ```

Crash dump was written to: `erl_crash.dump`

```
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

`Erlang` is running . Is it require to kill `Erlang` process.

```
[ttet@addr:17.566.98.656 Erlang]$:/ngs/app/ttet> ps -ef | grep erlang
ttet    13813 10547  0 11:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep erlang
ttet    32155     1  0 Oct08 ?        00:00:14 /ngs/app/ttet/softwares/Erlang/lib/erlang/erts-5.9/bin/epmd -daemon
```

Answer (score 14):

This helped me:

```
chmod 600 ~/.erlang.cookie
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rabbitmqctl start_app` only after you call `rabbitmqctl stop_app`. These commands starts/stops RabbitMQ application, not Erlang node. If you really killed RabbitMQ node you need to call `rabbitmq-server` to start RabbitMQ. Check is there RabbitMQ node running you can calling `ps -ef | grep rabbit`.

Also from your logs I figured out that the reason of errors is not appropriate .erlnag.cookie file access mode - {error_info,{exit,{"Cookie file /ngs/app/curot/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only".... Try to change it `chmod 600 /ngs/app/curot/.erlang.cookie` and start RabbitMQ server again.

It is not require to kill Erlang [epmd](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html) as it is a daemon that acts as a name server on all hosts involved in distributed Erlang computations and does not interfere on you RabbitMQ instance.

Comment: Thanks @sysoff . But,I have already solved this issue.But upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this.

First step is I have changed the permission to `/ngs/app/curot/.erlang.cookie`.

And 2nd step I used `rabbitmq-server -detached` command for start the rabbitmq.

Now its working for me.